# Get twitter first 300 tweets

Tags: python, twitter

So the Twitter API has a limit of 100 tweets when you search by keyword.
Example:

```
results = api.GetSearch(
raw_query="q=KeyordForSearch%20&result_type=recent&since=2014-07-19&count=100")
```

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Let's assume that the request above  would find 400 tweets matching.

The question is how can i send multiple requests that dont return the same tweets?
The first request will return 100 tweets, i want the second one to return the next 100(so i will have 200 **unique** tweets).

Comment: Did you read through https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search where it suggests how to approach retrieving multiple pages of results (for timeline and search) or considered a twitter library that does this for you? (tweepy springs to mind)

Comment: I just read what you pointed out and i can't seem to find anything there helping me. And yes, i'm currently using http://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html and i didnt find any library that would do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

After running the first search you should find the lowest ID of the results and pass it to the next query as **max_id**. This means that on the first search you will get the latest or the most popular 100 tweets, afterwords the next 100 and so forth.